# How to call square API to create card or how to charge with card info?

Tags: python, php, curl, postman, square-connect

**How to save customer card info - Squareup API**

> Postman API available for create customer card which is not helping me to charge with card
>   How would i save card info also

```
  "card_nonce": "YOUR_CARD_NONCE",
  "billing_address": {
    "address_line_1": "500 Electric Ave",
    "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
    "locality": "New York",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10003",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "cardholder_name": "Amelia Earhart",
  "verification_token": "TOKEN"
}

> Link Used to create : https://{{host}}/v2/customers/{{customer_id}}/cards
```

Answer (score 0):

**Got My Solution In git repo, this repo help i am able to charge card directly**

> https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/templates/web-ui/payment-form/basic

Comment: This link is dead